bin/gs_startnode fails to start on GridDB version 4.3.0

System: ubuntu18.04
version:4.3.0 griddb-4.3.0.tar.gz

I tried to compile and install the 4.3.0 version on ubuntu18.04. After compiling and installing, executing bin/gs_ Startnode, the program has an error, and the python 2.7 version is used. Is it the Python version?
wdgk@ubuntu:~/application/griddb/griddb-4.3.0$ bin/gs_startnode
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bin/gs_startnode", line 122, in <module>
    proc = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=f, stderr=f)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 394, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1047, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

